# How can one increase the timeout before the display dims when on the battery?

Tags: power-management, screen, brightness, battery, timeout

If I do not touch my computer (a Toshiba Satellite) for 15 seconds when running off the battery, the screen dims to the lowest brightness. I have already disabled "Dim screen to save power." I do not have this issue when my computer is connected to the charger. Is there any way to fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have any power-management softwares installed(eg. jupiter or tlp)?

Comment: @Jobin Yes, it seems that I do have tlp installed. I just checked /etc/default/tlp, but I don't see anything related to my problem. Thanks for the help.